# Error code 500 while saving location for Estimote Indoor Location

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, estimote, indoor-positioning-system

I had 3 indoor location beacons package with an email address and I get an error message during saving a location to estimate cloud.... the error message as below :-

**Error when saving location: Optional(Error Domain=ESTRequestBaseErrorDomain Code=500 "Estimote Cloud failed to handle request." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Estimote Cloud failed to handle request., NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Check reason field to verify what kind of error happened.})**

below is my implementation : -

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
// Override point for customization after application launch.
locationBuilder.setLocationName("my space")

locationBuilder.setLocationBoundaryPoints([
    EILPoint(x: 0.00, y: 0.00),
    EILPoint(x: 0.00, y: 9.85),
    EILPoint(x: 4.56, y: 9.85),
    EILPoint(x: 4.56, y: 0.00)])

locationBuilder.addBeacon(withIdentifier: "mybeaconid1", atBoundarySegmentIndex: 0, inDistance: 3.5, from: .leftSide)
locationBuilder.addBeacon(withIdentifier: "mybeaconid2", atBoundarySegmentIndex: 1, inDistance: 1.1, from: .rightSide)
locationBuilder.addBeacon(withIdentifier: "mybeaconid3", atBoundarySegmentIndex: 2, inDistance: 5.7, from: .leftSide)
locationBuilder.addBeacon(withIdentifier: "mybeacon4", atBoundarySegmentIndex: 3, inDistance: 3, from: .rightSide)

locationBuilder.setLocationOrientation(50)

let location = locationBuilder.build()

ESTConfig.setupAppID("myAppId", andAppToken: "myAppToken")

let addLocationRequest = EILRequestAddLocation(location: location!)

addLocationRequest.sendRequest { (location, error) in
    if error != nil {
        print("Error when saving location: \(String(describing: error))")
    } else {
        print("Location saved successfully: \(String(describing: location?.identifier))")
    }
}

beaconManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()

return true
}
```

Comment: https://forums.estimote.com/t/error-when-saving-location-estimote-cloud-failed-to-handle-request/6121/2 ?

Comment: I checked and i did purchased the hardware , a cloud account and a App with App Token

Comment: The response indicates that there is a server-side error, so most probably your code is correct. If there are any issues with your code, you have not set up your network request in the format the backend is expecting it and hence the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had asked the Estimate Support regarding this issue and this error happen due to some issue on their server and now this is working like a charm.